# Code to import data from csv file works on windows but not in kali linux apache2. every answer is apriciated

Tags: php, mysql, linux, csv, apache2

//im using this code to import data from a csv exel file to mysql database 
code works in windows wamp but not in linux apache2 
i dont understand why this is happening the logic is ok since it runs on windows

```
<?php  

include("dbcon.php");

if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("insert into client (nome,cognome, shenime) values 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    // 

    //redirect 
    header('Location: import.php?success=1'); die; 

} 

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<title>Import leads php csv</title> 
</head> 

<body> 

<?php if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?> 

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
  Choose your file: <br /> 
  <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: If it works on Windows and not on Linux, the first thing to check is case sensitivity: Is everything exactly the same in the file name, the table and column names, etc.?

Comment: I would check the line endings of the files you are parsing. Linux side may want "unix" line endings, and the csv file coming in may have DOS type ? Just a thought. - are any errors coming?

Comment: no it doesnt output any errors just a blank page with my html layout and its not in dos type i save the exel file in  csv format (comma delimited.csb)

Comment: *.csv  sry for the mistake

Comment: i imported the script above from windows to linux so everything is the same no changes in the php script

Comment: Fix #1 - `$_FILES['csv']['size']` (unless you've defined `csv` and `size` as constants; likewise with `tmp_name`

Comment: Fix #2 - `$data[0]` will be undefined in the first iteration, you'd be better using a standard `while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")) {...}` loop rather than `do { ... } while(...)`

Comment: i dint quite got the Fix #1 mark can u explain ty

Comment: THANK U IT WAS A DATABASE PRB LINUX DOESNT ALLOW FIELD WITH NO DEFAULT VALUES ON DATABASE TY

Comment: ANYONE HAS AN IDEA WHY WE CANT LEAVE A FIELD WITH DEFAULT VALUE 'NONE' ON LINUX MYSQL ?

Answer (score 0):

try this, when you save your file.csv in linux  in field options, field delimiter,  chose point and coma (;) and save.